Puppeteer does not generate .pdf file
I want to use puppeteer to generate pdf file by visiting my website. The problem is that while the screenshot method works fine, I can't produce pdf file. This is my code:

  async generatePdfByWisitingWebsite(user: UserEntity, data: InputGetPdfDto) {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, protocolTimeout: 500000 });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/login', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.type('#email', '...');
    await page.type('#password', '...');
    await page.click('#loginButton');

    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.goto('http://localhost:3000/app/account', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
    });

    const content = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML);
    console.log(content);

    await page.screenshot({ path: 'output/build1.png' });


    await page.pdf({
      path: 'output/test.pdf',
      format: 'A4',
      printBackground: true,
      margin: {
        top: '10mm',
        right: '10mm',
        bottom: '10mm',
        left: '10mm',
      },
      timeout: 0,
    });

    await browser.close();
  }

I'm watining for minutes and there is still no response. I tried with headless: false and the page loads correctly so not sure what am I doing wrong. Any ideas?

Your click/nav has a race conition. This is the correct idiom. If that doesn't fix the problem, please share a [mcve] so I can run your code and see the issue happening. Never use timeout: 0--it just stifles useful errors indefinitely. await page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML); can be await page.content(). Timeouts are discouraged.

It does not fix my problem. Everything works fine until calling page.pdf

OK, but I need a runnable [mcve] to help still. I don't have your site or username or password, and other than the aside antipatterns I've suggested above, there's nothing obviously wrong with the PDF call on sight.

Even the official example does not work on my machine: https://pptr.dev/guides/pdf-generation
I've got Timed out after waiting 30000ms but even when setting it to 0 the call never ends. What might be the reason?

You might want to provide system details then, since their official example is correct. Just ran it on Ubuntu 22.04 / Puppeteer 22.7.1 without any issues.

I'm running it simply on my nestjs backend in dev mode. Is there sth wrong with that? How to cehck system details?

What server operating system and version? Which Puppeteer version? You're running the exact same code as the Puppeteer example you linked, generating a PDF of Hacker News? Try running it without NestJS and ensure it works in the simplest form. If it fails, what error (if any) is logged? Just a standard timeout on the .pdf() call? pdf() can fail if fonts don't load, so remove all of your fonts if you haven't minimized that yet. I need details and a [mcve] or steps to reproduce this, otherwise I can't really help.

My computer is on Windows 10 Home. I'm running nestjs app in dev mode and puppetter is in the latest version (22.10.0). I'm running exactly the same code as in docs. In not headless mode the page opens correctly but it stacks on pdf generation It does not fails if I set timeout to 0 but it never ends the job.

I'm getting  Page.printToPDF timed out. Increase the 'protocolTimeout' setting in launch/connect calls for a higher timeout if needed. but again when settings protocolTimeout to 0 the process never ends

Yeah don't use timeout: 0, that doesn't fix the problem, just hides the useful error that you want to see because it shows you what's wrong. OK, well unfortunately I can't reproduce this after upgrading to Pupp 22.10.0 on Ubuntu 22.04, so I'll leave the thread to someone who can. You may want to simplify your question to just say you can't run the exact code from the pdf example, helping remove whatever you're running on localhost from the picture.

Maybe  could downlaod another puppeteer version? Which one would you recommend?

I recommend the latest because it works for me. I have no idea what the problem might be on your end, so you could try random versions to see if any work.

Just had a similar issue on Windows. There is a GitHub issue being tracked right now on Puppeteer regarding PDF hanging specifically on Windows.
They say it's a permissions related issue on downloaded Chrome files that Puppeteer does not currently have control over. The GitHub issue links to this website from puppeter devs as a work around.
Personally that workaround worked! One note: I had to use icacls %USERPROFILE%/.cache/puppeteer/chrome /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(RX)" over using $HOME, however.
Also remember to keep headless to true per this question.
